# Difference between Set method and SetScoped method in MappedDiagnosticsLogicalContext Class

Tags: c#, logging, nlog

In NLog there are two methods `Set` and `SetScoped` in `MappedDiagnosticsLogicalContext` Class

Does `SetScoped` method sets the scope to - per request and if yes - what would be the scope for `Set` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Set` and the `SetScoped` are doing basically the same thing, except that the `SetScoped` returns a `IDisposable` which you could dispose for un-setting the value.

e.g. With `Set`

```
MappedDiagnosticsLogicalContext.Set("key1", "value1");
DoSomething();
MappedDiagnosticsLogicalContext.Remove("key1");
```

vs `SetScoped`

```
using(MappedDiagnosticsLogicalContext.SetScoped("key1", "value1"))
{
    DoSomething();
}
```

The scope of the MappedDiagnosticsLogicalContext (MDLC) is the current thread and childs threads. So without remove/dispose it will be available on those threads. See also: [MDLC docs](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/MDLC-Layout-Renderer)

Comment: Thanks Julian for the quick answer - appreciate your explanation...